# How can i check the color of the closest object in unity?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have logic like in this game https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nbstudio.towercolor&hl=ru. They have logic, when ball strike and touch the cylinder and if nearby objects had the same color of the ball, it has been destroyed. I've try to make a 2d array of my objects which spawn when playmode run, but i don't have any ideas how can i check the color of objects.

```cs
public class DestroingObjects : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> objects;

    public GameObject[,] game;
    public GameObject[] gameObjects;

    [SerializeField]
    private float timeLeft;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject prefab;

    [SerializeField]
    Material colorOfPlayer;

    [SerializeField]
    MeshRenderer[,] mesh;

    [SerializeField]
    private TowerCreator tower;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tower = FindObjectOfType<TowerCreator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            timeLeft = 1;
            gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object");

            game = new GameObject[tower.pieceCount, tower.levelsOfTowerCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < tower.pieceCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < tower.levelsOfTowerCount; j++)
                {
                    game[i, j] = gameObjects[i];
                    Debug.Log(game.Length);
                    findColors();

                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    public void findColors()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tower.pieceCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tower.levelsOfTowerCount; j++)
            {
                var mesh = game[i, j].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
                Debug.Log(mesh.material.color);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to check the "physical" color of the object (as presented by the `Renderer`). What you need is an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) containing all available colors in your game, since you want to use them as identifiers:

```
public enum MyColor {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
    public MyColor BallColor;
}

public class Cylinder : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private MyColor myColor;
    
    private void Start() {
        // set the renderers color ("physical" color) to a desired rgb value 
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = TranslateEnumToColor(myColor);
    }

    private static Color TranslateEnumToColor(MyColor c) {
        ...
    }

    ...
    
    // call this, when ball hits cylinder
    public void BallHitMe(Ball theHittingBall) {
        if(theHittingBall.BallColor == myColor) {
            Debug.Log("colors do match, destroy me now");
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can get the color identifier (MyColor) without having to worry about things like `Renderer` (or Textures, if you want to add something fancier in the future).

Answer (score 0):

When you check objects.color it is checking multiple floats

.color is color(r,g,b,a) red, green,blue,alpha
so if you want to display as debug you need to further narrow it to its values:
Debug.log("r="+spriteRenderer.color.r +" g="+ spriteRenderer.color.g +" b="+ spriteRenderer.color.b);